# i installed ubuntu 16.4.2 as primary only os but it reboots windows 7

Tags: system-installation

My current OS is windows 7 32 bit, but my  processor support 64 bit so i downloaded ubuntu 16.4.2 (64 bit) from the official site, i installed it successfully as primary os but when it rebooted, windows 7 still there and there is no ubuntu !!
i'm newbie in ubuntu and i'm really upset

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss the Grub installation?

Comment: Is Ubuntu the "only" operating system or the "primary* operating system in a dual-boot set-up? Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: (Replace windows with ubuntu/install ubuntu alongside windows) screen didn't show up during installation